# Valgrind - Memory Leaks When Duplicating/Freeing Arrays

Tags: c

I'm messing around with allocating and deallocating memory to get the hang of it. Below, I take in string arguments from the command line (`char **argv`) and try to duplicate them as uppercase strings in another malloc'd array:

```
static char **duplicateArgs(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc <= 1) {
        printf("%s\n", "No strings to duplicate.");
        exit(1);
    }
    char **duplicate = (char**)malloc((argc + 1) * sizeof(char**));

    int i = 1;
    int j = 0;
    int stringLength;

    while (argv[i]) {
        stringLength = strlen(argv[i]);
        duplicate[i] = (char*)malloc(stringLength * sizeof(char) + 1);
        for (j = 0; j < stringLength; j++) {
            duplicate[i][j] = toupper(argv[i][j]);
        }
        duplicate[i][j]= '\0';
        i++;
    }
    duplicate[i] = NULL;
    return duplicate;
}
```

I have a function that frees them as well:

```
static void freeDuplicateArgs(char **copy) {
    int i = 0;
    while (copy[i]) {
        if (copy[i] != NULL){
            free(copy[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (copy != NULL){
        free(copy);
        }
}
```

In the `main` function, I call these methods, print them out and then free them:

```
    char **copy = duplicateArgs(argc, argv);
    char **p = copy;

    argv++;
    p++;
    while(*argv) {
        printf("%s %s\n", *argv++, *p++);
    }

    freeDuplicateArgs(copy);
    return 0;
```

The output works as expected, printing out the string regularly and then printing it out in caps. However, when I check it against Valgrind, I get this mess:

```
==20867== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==20867==    at 0x100000D1A: freeDuplicateArgs (part2.c:32)
==20867==    by 0x100000E19: main (part2.c:57)
==20867== 
==20867== 
==20867== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20867==     in use at exit: 62,847 bytes in 368 blocks
==20867==   total heap usage: 520 allocs, 152 frees, 66,761 bytes allocated
==20867== 
==20867== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20867==    definitely lost: 8,639 bytes in 18 blocks
==20867==    indirectly lost: 1,168 bytes in 5 blocks
==20867==      possibly lost: 4,925 bytes in 68 blocks
==20867==    still reachable: 48,115 bytes in 277 blocks
==20867==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Why am I getting such a memory mess if the compiler is raising no errors for my freeDuplicates method and my output is okay?

Edit: I Should also mention that I'm on OSX 10.8 -- apparently Valgrind has some issues with that...

Comment: poor question title. -1

Comment: `char **duplicate = (char**)malloc((argc + 1) * sizeof(char**));` You're off by one level of indirection here, though that's not causing your problem.

Comment: @EdwardBird - A useful title helps people in the future to find a relevant answer or possible duplicates.

Comment: @EdHeal A sense of humour makes the world a brighter place - I hope in the future there will be more questions with titles like these. It's not a hilarious title exactly, but it made me chuckle.

Comment: @EdwardBird - I agree about your comments about humour but people do use this site as a resource. I look up a problem and the title does help to find out what posts to examine. A lot simpler - A lot quicker than posting a question.

Comment: @EdwardBird Humour is fun but it should not take the place of a _useful_ title. This is a programming Q&A and not a circus.

Comment: For the record, the original title was "Why Does Valgrind Hate Me?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Freeing code

Your freeing code is interesting — not precisely wrong, but not really right, either:

```
static void freeDuplicateArgs(char **copy) {
    int i = 0;
    while (copy[i]) {
        if (copy[i] != NULL){
            free(copy[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (copy != NULL){
        free(copy);
    }
}
```

You test for `copy != NULL` just before freeing it, but you've been using it all along, so the test is redundant there.  Besides, you can do `free(NULL)` without running into problems.

Then we look at the loop:

```
 while (copy[i] != NULL)
 {
     if (copy[i] != NULL)
```

The loop condition and the if condition are identical — and again, you can `free(NULL)`.

Your while loop has the structure of a for loop written out.  You'd do better with:

```
static void freeDuplicateArgs(char **copy)
{
    if (copy != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 0; copy[i] != NULL; i++)
            free(copy[i]);
        free(copy);
    }
}
```

The test for `copy != NULL` prevents crashes, and only freeing it when it is known to be non-null is a (very, very) minor optimization.

I doubt that this is directly the cause of the problems (I'll look a bit harder at the rest of the code in a moment), but it is something to consider.

#### Allocating code

You have:

```
static char **duplicateArgs(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc <= 1) {
        printf("%s\n", "No strings to duplicate.");
        exit(1);
    }
```

First of all, a program can be invoked with no user arguments but it still has `argv[0]`, the program name and a NULL pointer.  Your code should probably simply handle the negative values by returning `(char **)NULL`.  For 0 arguments, you return a pointer to a null pointer.  And for one or more arguments, there is work to do.

Consider the line:

```
duplicate[i] = (char*)malloc(stringLength * sizeof(char) + 1);
```

There are two cases that you might consider: `sizeof(char) == 1` and `sizeof(char) > 1` (yes, hold on — wait!).  If `sizeof(char) == 1`, then you don't need to multiply by it.  If `sizeof(char) > 1`, you aren't allocating enough space; the expression should be `(stringLength + 1) * sizeof(char)`.  So, write one of these two lines:

```
duplicate[i] = (char*)malloc((stringLength + 1) * sizeof(char));
duplicate[i] = (char*)malloc(stringLength + 1);
```

I note that the C standard says that `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition, so the actual result is the same, but if you were dealing with arrays of `int` or something else, getting the multiplication by `sizeof(type)` in the right place could be crucial.

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators
>
> ¶4 When `sizeof` is applied to an operand that has type `char`, `unsigned char`, or
> `signed char`, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1.

#### Valgrind on Mac OS X 10.7.5

Taking your code almost as written in the question:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static char **duplicateArgs(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc <= 1) {
        printf("%s\n", "No strings to duplicate.");
        exit(1);
    }
    char **duplicate = (char**)malloc((argc + 1) * sizeof(char**));

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int stringLength;

    while (argv[i]) {
        stringLength = strlen(argv[i]);
        duplicate[i] = (char*)malloc(stringLength * sizeof(char) + 1);
        for (j = 0; j < stringLength; j++) {
            duplicate[i][j] = toupper(argv[i][j]);
        }
        duplicate[i][j]= '\0';
        i++;
    }
    duplicate[i] = NULL;
    return duplicate;
}

static void freeDuplicateArgs(char **copy)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (copy[i]) {
        if (copy[i] != NULL){
            free(copy[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (copy != NULL){
        free(copy);
        }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char **copy = duplicateArgs(argc, argv);
    char **p = copy;

    argv++;
    p++;
    while(*argv) {
        printf("%s %s\n", *argv++, *p++);
    }

    freeDuplicateArgs(copy);
    return 0;
}
```

(The difference is the `int i = 0;` in this working code instead of `int i = 1;` in the question code.)

When run under `valgrind`, this gets a clean bill of health:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition mlk.c -o mlk
$ valgrind ./mlk nuts oh hazelnuts
==582== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==582== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==582== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==582== Command: ./mlk nuts oh hazelnuts
==582== 
nuts NUTS
oh OH
hazelnuts HAZELNUTS
==582== 
==582== HEAP SUMMARY:
==582==     in use at exit: 18,500 bytes in 33 blocks
==582==   total heap usage: 38 allocs, 5 frees, 18,564 bytes allocated
==582== 
==582== LEAK SUMMARY:
==582==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==582==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==582==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==582==    still reachable: 18,500 bytes in 33 blocks
==582==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==582== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==582== 
==582== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==582== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
$
```

As you can see, there are no memory errors reported.  The 33 blocks still in use is 'normal' for this machine; they're allocated by the Mac OS X C runtime library.  I haven't got `valgrind` on a Mac OS X 10.8 system to compare with.  I recommend you try running a very simple program under `valgrind` and see what it tells you:

```
int main(void) { return 0; }
```

That will be the baseline for your system.  If there are leaks, they are not caused by your code, and you'll need to learn how to record suppressions so that your programs are not penalized for the transgressions of the O/S.

If you run the simple program above and find that it doesn't produce leaks — or the leaks are radically simpler and smaller — then try some slightly more complex programs:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    void *vp = malloc(32);
    free(vp);
    return(0);
}
```

This ensures that `malloc()` is dragged in and used, but clearly doesn't leak (and it handles `malloc()` failure correctly too!).

#### `valgrind` support for Mac OS X 10.8

The [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) web site says:

> 18 September 2012: valgrind-3.8.1, for X86/Linux, AMD64/Linux, ARM/Linux, PPC32/Linux, PPC64/Linux, S390X/Linux, MIPS/Linux, ARM/Android (2.3.x and later), X86/Android (4.0 and later), X86/Darwin and AMD64/Darwin (Mac OS X 10.6 and 10.7, with limited support for 10.8) is available.

What you're seeing may be an aspect of the limited support for Mac OS X 10.8.

I see I need to rebuild `valgrind` for myself (3.7.0 is not current).

Comment: Thank you for the great tips on memory freeing. It turns out that the strange output I was still getting after initializing i to 0 in the right place was the default output for a "clean bill of health." So I guess I'll have to use that as my baseline measurement until OSX 10.8 support is added.

Comment: It is mildly annoying that you have to calibrate `valgrind` like that.  It is doubly worrisome that Mac OS X 10.8 seems to actually leak memory, and that its overhead has grown (from about 18.5 KB to almost 63 KB).  I usually don't show the details when responding to `valgrind` questions because of the questions the summary raises, but this time, it seemed likely to be helpful to you — which seems to have been the correct choice.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're never setting `duplicate[0]` to anything, so when you use `copy[i]` in `freeDuplicateArgs`, starting with i=0, you don't know what will happen.

Comment: Good point. But even when I fix that by initializing i to 0 instead of 1 in duplicateArgs, I'm still getting similar errors.